# Can't see LIST of MYSQL UDFs

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, user-defined-functions

I need a way to see a list of MYSQL UDFs (User Defined Functions).
I use the phpmysql interface.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a list of stored procedures/functions, You can do:

```
select * from information_schema.routines;
```

From [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/routines-table.html)

If you are looking for UDF's you can do:

```
select * from mysql.func;
```

From [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-function-udf.html)